# html5 css3 fluid layout with flexible background images

Tags: html, css, background-image, vertical-alignment, fluid-layout

I'm working on a mobile web app (later planning to convert same to native app using phonegap) which uses HTML5 + CSS3 + jQueryMobile 1.2.0. I'm not good at css3 and html5 but trying to learn and develop a mobile site. Everything going fine till i got a screen where i should add a background image to text. I'm targeting 320*480 - 1280*798 screens. So, Every where my site should look good and same. So im adding fiddle of my html and css and adding screenshots.

my requirements:

- two images left and right should be flexible according to screen size (320 - 1280)
- text on centre should be centre aligned (horizontal + vertical).
- there is a text on right side image that also should be centre aligned (horizontal + vertical).

fiddle of my code [HTML + CSS Code](http://jsfiddle.net/NxuYC/)

it resulting on firefox (1280*768) as below (almost as I want).

[screen shot on firefox and android emulator](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/502/firefoxkd.png/)

But, when i run same on android emulator (320*480), its not aligned properly

So, please let me know how to align content along with background image / direct image. ultimately my screen should look as in firefox.

Thanks in advance.